# How to Pass HTML Textbox Input Into Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'm making dynamic js code that will involve user text input. When the user enters the text, the JavaScript variable I'm creating will changed based on that. It does not return the user input, however.

I tried using the example listed, where I make a form, assign it a value, and try to reference it in my JavaScript. I've looked at many articles before coming here, and none of them answer MY question. The code always returns the value in the actual HTML tag as opposed to user input.

Whenever I use this, for example;

```
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="textie" value="TypeHere">
    </form>
```

and try to get it using something like this...

```
    var userInput = document.getElementById('TypeHere').value;
```

...the page returns "TypeHere" instead of the user input. What am I doing wrong?

I expect to see user input but it always returns the value (TypeHere, in this case).

Comment: When should be the value retrieved? On `change`, on `click` etc. you need `event`.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `document.getElementById` you have to use ID NOT value.

```js
function printText(){
 var userInput = document.getElementById('dd').value;
 alert(userInput)}
```

```html
<form>
    <input id = "dd" type="text" name="textie" onchange="printText()" >
    </form>
```

Comment: You could also use `document.querySelector('input[name=textie]')`

Answer (score 0):

Specify two things:

- event, when your function should be called.
- the function itself

```js
function myfunc(val) {
  alert(val)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="textie" value="TypeHere" onchange="myFunc(this.value)">
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp